# Javascript is not working for max/min button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am doing maximize/minimize button functionality.my javascript code is not working.suggest me any solution for it.thanks in advance.

here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$(function () {
   $(".button-open").hide();
   $(".button-close").bind("click", function () {
     $(".box").hide(100);        

     if ($(this).attr("class") == "button-close")
     {
       $(".button-open").show();
     }
  });
});

$(".button-open").bind("click", function () {
  $(".box").show(100);        
  if ($(this).attr("class") == "button-open")
  {
    $(".button-open").hide();
  }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="button-open">Open</div>
<div class="box">
<div class="button-close">X</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will require you to link to the **jQuery library** since you are using `jQuery` Also would it not be easier to use something like `.toggle()` rather than having to swap the classes and bind two event listeners, also you appear to be missing the class attribute change "assuming you want to allow the client to open/show that element if closed or close it if open"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always remember to include the JQuery file before you use the JQuery syntax. If you do not want to use JQuery then you need to write pure Javascript. But it will be an easy fix for you if you just reference the JQuery in your HTML.

```js
$(function () {
$(".box").hide(); 
$(".button-close").bind("click", function () {
$(".box").hide(100);        

if ($(this).attr("class") == "button-close")
{
  $(".button-open").show();
}
});
});

$(".button-open").bind("click", function () {
$(".box").show(100);        
if ($(this).attr("class") == "button-open")
{
  $(".button-open").hide();
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-open">Open</div>
<div class="box">
<div class="button-close">X</div>
```

Comment: ya its working!!thanks,but i want to be open button first.suggest me how to do that.

Comment: That is very simple. I have edited my answer please check and if it is what you want please up vote it also.

Comment: Happy to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Add jquery library before your script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why is it best practice to add it before the end of the body tag? As long as you include the library before running the script it won't make any difference. Adding scripts after the page content is normally done when people don't know or want to use a DOM ready events but the OP's source code is clearly using the DOM ready function provided by `jQuery` **-** `$(function(){ });`

Comment: I agree with @NewToJS. The note of wahdan just do not make any sense.

Comment: yes,its working but when run my code that X comes first but i want to be open button first,how to do that?

Comment: @NewToJS @AKA i totally agree with you ,but many developers forget to add `$(function(){ });` which will lead unexpected errors

Comment: @wahdan then it would be best practice for them to not forget to use such basic function and those developers should read the documentation for those libraries/plug-ins before using them. I still don't think that justifies such note of best practice.

Comment: @NewToJS ok i will remove it .